# Error installing dotnet "Requires openssl-libs"

Tags: linux, .net-core, amazon-linux

I'm try install dotnet by command for OS Amazon Linux 2 AMI

```
sudo yum install -y dotnet-sdk-2.1.4
```

And it show for me:

> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
>
> amzn-main          | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
>
> amzn-updates       | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
>
> Resolving Dependencies
>
> --> Running transaction check
>
> ---> Package dotnet-sdk-2.1.4.x86_64 0:2.1.4-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5 >= 2.0.5 for package: dotnet-sdk-2.1.4-2.1.4-1.x86_64
>
> --> Processing Dependency: aspnetcore-store-2.0.5 >= 2.0.5 for package: dotnet-sdk-2.1.4-2.1.4-1.x86_64
>
> --> Running transaction check
>
> ---> Package aspnetcore-store-2.0.5.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: aspnetcore-store-2.0.3 >= 2.0.3 for package: aspnetcore-store-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> ---> Package dotnet-runtime-2.0.5.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs for package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> --> Processing Dependency: dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5 for package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> --> Running transaction check
>
> ---> Package aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.x86_64 0:2.0.3-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: aspnetcore-store-2.0.0 >= 2.0.0 for package: aspnetcore-store-2.0.3-2.0.3-1.x86_64
>
> ---> Package dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: dotnet-host >= 2.0.5 for package: dotnet-hostfxr-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> ---> Package dotnet-runtime-2.0.5.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs for package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> --> Running transaction check
>
> ---> Package aspnetcore-store-2.0.0.x86_64 0:2.0.0-1 will be installed
>
> ---> Package dotnet-host.x86_64 0:2.1.0-1 will be installed
>
> ---> Package dotnet-runtime-2.0.5.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1 will be installed
>
> --> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs for package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64
>
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>   Error: Package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.5-2.0.5-1.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-prod)
>
> Requires: openssl-libs
>
> You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>
> You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

I enter

```
 sudo yum list
```

And i can't found openssl-libs in result.

Also i installed openssl-devel, but result is same.

**Update:**
I compared the used repositories to another server. There it was installed successfully.

*First server repository* repository: !amzn-main/latest, os version: "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"

*Second server repository (with installed dotnet)* repository: !amzn2-core/2017.12/x86_64, os version: "Amazon Linux 2 (2017.12) LTS Release Candidate"

I think yum cannot get openssl-libs from repository. How can I install this package?

Comment: Seems your "Amazon Linux 2 AM" is an older version : `openssl-libs` came first time with Fedora 17. ( CentOS 6 is based on Fedora 12, 13 and CentOS 7 on Fedora 19, 20 ).

Comment: @Knud Larsen, I used this distribution on a different server earlier. There dotnet was successfully installed and the version was more old.

Comment: Example, openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64 https://www.dropbox.com/s/a12mlgkom21ovb6/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64.txt?dl=0 . ... Please check if the files are provided by another package.

Comment: Do you get a solution to it?

Comment: @DeepakKumbhar have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue while installing Powershell. I managed to fake the installation of the latest CentOS package like this:

```
sudo rpm -ivh https://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.9.2009/updates/x86_64/Packages/openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el7_9.x86_64.rpm --justdb  --force
```

The `--justdb --force` added it to the RPM database but without touching the filesystem.

Comment: Have to be careful, this meant I couldn't get an update for the regular openssl library because it conflicted with the openssl-lib forcedly installed, and uninstalling openssl-lib could accidently removed the libraries needed to make yum work.